# Check if h2 database already exists using clojure?

Tags: clojure, h2, exists

I have a clojure project and I want to use a h2 database with it. Is there a way to check if the database exists? I tried something like this:

```
(defn mysql-db [] 
  (if (.exists (clojure.java.io/as-file "my-webapp.h2.db"))
    (println "exists")
    (j/with-connection
      {:classname "org.h2.Driver"
       :subprotocol "h2:file"
       :subname "db/my-webapp"}

      (j/create-table :locations
                      [:id "bigint primary key auto_increment"]
                      [:title "varchar (255)"]
                      [:part "clob"])

      (j/insert-records :locations
                        {:title "Steven Gerrard: I'm not the new Beckham"
                         :part "He might not have the Becks appeal -- but Steven Gerrard says he's ready to light up Hollywood in his own way..."}))))
```

But the `.exists` function always returns false.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the

```
 (if (.exists (clojure.java.io/as-file "my-webapp.h2.db"))
```

line into

```
 (if (.exists (clojure.java.io/as-file "db/my-webapp.h2.db"))
```

and it works. I guess I was not looking in the right folder.